# Is $P(Y > X + c) \leq P(Y > X)$ for any random variables $X,Y$ and non-negative constant $c$?

Tags: probability

Does this hold in the general case? It seems intuitive that this should always be the case since adding a non-negative constant to a random variable will thus make it the same or larger, and therefore the probability of $Y$ being greater should never increase.

How do you actually prove this formally?

Answer (score 4):

Because holds $\{\omega \colon Y(\omega) \gt X(\omega)+c  \} \subset \{\omega \colon Y(\omega) \gt X(\omega)  \}$ for $c \gt 0$, then we can say $P(Y > X + c) \leqslant P(Y > X)$.